# How to enable implicitCachingEnabled (statement caching) from Tomcat for oracle?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I've been reading about implicitCachingEnabled and MaxStatements with the oracle jdbc driver.

I've tried adding implicitCachingEnabled="true" into the server.xml for the datasource definition but it makes no difference.

I've also noted other posts admittedly from a long time ago, where people have failed to get this setting to work simply by setting it in the tomcat config files.

So just on the offchance someone has it working, is there a trick to it?

In the mean time i'll investigate whether it's possible or not to do this via code, but we're using JPA so i'm not sure how that'll work!

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the value OracleConnection.setStatementCacheSize () instead of MaxStatements

http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/java.101/b10979/stmtcach.htm

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it didnt seem to work.  I still see soft parses in the DB.  I've asked our java dev to have a look at doing it explicitly in the code, just to see whether this works as expected or not. Thanks!